# Can I Check the App Size Before I Create the "ipa" File?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way to check my app size before I create the ipa file for app store upload?
i.e. while I work on my app (adding content and methods) - I want to check what would the app size be if I had created the ipa file as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you build a target, under products, you can see the app file there, you can reveal it in finder and check out its size..

Comment: I have 3 app files in the app folder in Finder. any idea why or which one is the relevant one?

Comment: why do you have three? do you have three products? You can clean your project and the app images will go away, then rebuild one of the targets and it should be the only one in there

Answer (score 4):

An .ipa file is typically a ZIP file with a ".ipa" extension instead of ".zip". This ZIP/IPA file contains some metadata, and the compiled app itself.

- You can't forcast the size of an app before compiling it, for many reasons, especially the fact that the compiler will make some optimizations of your code and so on.
- You can't either forcast the size of the IPA, because it will be the result of the ZIP (LZW) compression on the APP payload (+ some other files), and the compression process is also dependant of the content (e.g. compressing a text file using LZW/ZIP will result in a file that is more or less big depending on the fact that the text contains more or less repetitions, etc).

The only thing you may do is that you can check the sum of the sizes of all your resource files, especially images, video, sounds, etc... you add to your project & app, because of course adding a very big image file will impact the size of your final app bundle and thus the size of your IPA. But that would only be an unprecise approximation on how your final IPA size will change when adding files, without taking the LZW/ZIP compression into account anyway.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Well explained and cool concepts.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 4.3.1, you can select target as IOS Device and from Product menu choose Archive. It creates the archive. You can view the archive detail from Window->Organizer. There you will